# Client session cookies

Tags: http, session-cookies, csrf-protection

I'm developing a website using Flask and I'm looking at how sessions are implemented. Flask stores session data inside a cryptographically signed cookie therefore sessions are stored on client side.

Assuming data stored in the cookie is already known by the client (no sensitive data to hide from the client), what are the issues of this approach? Is it safe to store CSRF token in client side cookies as long as it is signed?